# Displaying images in scrollView are not correct

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, tableview

I want to display my images in a scroll view within my custom tableViewCell. It does display some images but they are wrong. I believe it's due to the fact that they are being reused so where there shouldn't be images, it gets displayed anways.

furthermore, my images get brighter/darker because when i scroll up or down, it gets created again, thus layering more scrollViews on top of each other or just the images.

```
//global
var masterImageArray = Array<Array<UIImage>>() //holds ALL of my images

//other info for my scrollview to use
let imageWidth: CGFloat = 100
let imageHeight: CGFloat = 200
let yPosition: CGFloat = 0
var xPosition: CGFloat = 0
var scrollViewContentSize: CGFloat = 0


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: FriendsFeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! FriendsFeedTableViewCell

    // holds array of UIImages to display in scrollView
    let images = masterImageArray[indexPath.row] 

    //scrollView to display images ([UIImage])

        for var i = 0; i < images.count; i++ { //images will vary

            let myImage: UIImage = images[i]

            let myImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()

            myImageView.image = myImage

            myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
            myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
            myImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition

            cell.imageScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)

            xPosition = imageWidth
            scrollViewContentSize += imageWidth

            cell.imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContentSize, height: imageHeight)
        }
}
```

My question is, how can I display them properly and how can I stop the "reuse" or from creating others on top of each other. Should Have I put this code inside the tableViewCell file?

**----EDIT: 1------**

After following @joern 's advice, I went along used 3 UIImageViews which will show the images instead of creating and destroying each UIImageView.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: FriendsFeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! FriendsFeedTableViewCell

    let images = masterImageArray[indexPath.row]

    var imageViews = [UIImageView]()

    imageViews.append(cell.imageView_1)
    imageViews.append(cell.imageView_2)
    imageViews.append(cell.imageView_3)

    for var i = 0; i < images.count; i++ {
        imageViews[i].image = images[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues here:

1. You don't increment `xPosition`

It should be:

```
xPosition = 0
for var i = 0; i < images.count; i++ { //images will vary
    ...
    xPosition += imageWidth
    ....
}
```

2. You don't reset the images from the cell before it is reused.

You have to reset your images before a cell is reused. You do that in your custom cell class. To make that work you should move all the image related code to your cell class. Keep your imageViews in an Array to access them and reset them in `prepareForReuse`. To keep thing simple I assume in this example that a cell never has more than 3 images:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let imageViews = [UIImageView]()
    ....

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        for _ in 0...2 {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            // setup and position the image view in your scroll view
            imageViews.append(imageView)
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        for imageView in imageViews {
            imageView.image = nil
        }
    }

    func updateImages(images: [UIImage]) {
        var imageIndex = 0
        for image in images {
            imageViews[imageIndex].image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Then from in your view controller in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you call `updateImages` on your dequeued cell. `prepareForReuse` is automatically called by the system, you don't call it yourself.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: FriendsFeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! FriendsFeedTableViewCell
    cell.updateImages(masterImageArray[indexPath.row])
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are most certainly right about the performance issues. I did set up a scrollView along with 3 imageViews that I could use to populate my images. I created this before I posted this question. I didn't know how to add the images to their corresponding images....

Comment: The easiest way would be to keep the image views in an Array and then iterate over the images that the cell should have and set `imageViews[i] = image[i]`. Just make sure that you have enough imageViews for all the images (create new ones and add them to the Array if you don't) and that you hide the other imageViews that are not needed for the cell. If you do it like that you wouldn't even need the `prepareForReuse` method.

Comment: Joe, I updated my post. It works, but when the 'images' array is empty, i'll scroll down then up to the empty ones, it fills the ImageViews are filled with other images. This would mean that I would just hide/unhide the imageView. How do you recommend I do that. I posted my current code.

Comment: You are still adding the imageViews to cells every time a cell is reused. You have to move the image creation to the initializer of the cell class. I updated my answer, please have a look.